# launch .jar as a different user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jar, executable-jar

In ubuntu I am logged in as a standard user (with restricted privileges) and I would like to launch a .jar as the admin user, what would be the best way of doing this from the command line?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use standard tools, i.e. sudo:

```
sudo java -jar yourjar.jar
```

As different user:

```
sudo -u anyuser java -jar yourjar.jar
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but this will run the application as root? I would like to run the application as a specific user, is that possible?